# Simplification of a JacobiCN Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Consider the following indefinite integral:

```
 Assuming[A > 0 && B > 0 , 
     Integrate[1/(1 - A JacobiCN[B x, k]^2), x] // FullSimplify]
```

> -((EllipticPi[A/(-1 + A), JacobiAmplitude[B x, k], k] JacobiDN[B x, 
>      k])/((-1 + A) B Sqrt[1 - k JacobiSN[B x, k]^2]))

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to simplify the indefinite integral further, maybe using some elementary functions that somehow Mathematica doesn't want to use ?
2. How does this result of integration compare to that in Maple?(I don't use myself, so I am soliciting some result from anyone who uses Maple)

Comment: What about `k` and `x` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk k is as usual(0<=k<=1) while x is any real no

Answer (score 1):

For general ,probably no,if you choose a value for `k` and use `FunctionExpand`, you will get simpler answers.

```
int = Integrate[1/(1 - A JacobiCN[B x, k]^2), x];
Table[int, {k, 0, 1, 1/2}] // FunctionExpand // MatrixForm
```

[image]

---

`Maple 2018` answer:

[image]

Comment: I think Maple's general answer is a wee bit better than Mathematica's.